# android: error fetching location on Microsoft Surface device

Tags: android, windows, android-location, windows-subsystem-for-android

I am trying to run Android app on Windows Surface Pro using Windows Subsystem for Android. While I try to fetch the location, I don't see any error on the screen, but I found the below log on the logcat:

> com.xxx.xxx requires the Google Play Store, but it is missing. The
> service for com.google.android.gms.common.internal.service.zar is not
> available: ConnectionResult{statusCode=SERVICE_INVALID,
> resolution=null, message=null}

Also, after this action app is not responding to touch events anymore. Can someone help me solve this?

Any help/pointers would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Currently Windows Subsystem for Android don't have Google Services, if your app relies on FusedLocationProvider then it won't be able to get the location. Hence for now it is recommended to use Android's Location Service

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33671310)